# Where to save javascript for Adobe Acrobat on a Mac?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

Hi I have a javascript but am completely new to Macs, where would I save the file .js file to in my Mac to make it work with Adobe Acrobat Pro? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you mentioned a .js file, I'm assuming you mean application-level scripts. Those go in the directory below.

/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/DC/JavaScripts/